# How to randomise an array with certain criterion fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of elements. I want to randomise the position of the elements but I want certain criterion to be fulfilled in the output of the randomized array.

```
var array = [1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2];
```

What I have done so far is used a function to randomize the order of the array. However, I don't know how to include these criteria into the function.
Here is the function that I am using:

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var len = array.length, temp; // While there are elements in the array
    while (ctr > 0) {
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * len); // Pick a random index
        ctr--; // Decrease ctr by 1
        temp = array[len]; // And swap the last element with it
        array[len] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    }
    return array;
};
```

I want this array to be randomized but also that the 2s in the array should not come consecutively after the randomization. I want the output to be somewhat like this.

```
var array = [2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1];
```

Any help in this respect would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: You should at least start with a common implementation, then it should be obvious how achieve your expected output, cheers

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. Your criterion makes the output less random in theory, while it might LOOK more random to a human viewer. That said, what is your goal, what is the use case that should be achieved?

Comment: It would be helpful if you also post the code of what you have so far.

Comment: I would simply chunk the inputs first, basically get all 2's and add one of the 1's to the end of these chunks, randomise all the chunks, eg. `[[2,1], [2,1], [2,1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]`,  If you randomise this, and then flatten you won't get two 2's next to each other.

Comment: Thank you! I shall try this. Looks like it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use [Keith'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66901129/how-to-randomise-an-array-with-certain-criterion-fulfilled/66901801#comment118258857_66901129) approach

> I would simply chunk the inputs first, basically get all 2's and add one of the 1's to the end of these chunks, randomise all the chunks, eg. `[[2,1], [2,1], [2,1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]`, If you randomise this, and then flatten you won't get two 2's next to each other.

with a small change:

1. Take a all wanted pairs with the spaced items `2` and non spaced items `1`, take the non spaced items and an extra spaced item.

   ```
   [
       [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]
   ]
   ```
2. Shuffle array.
3. Flat array.
4. Decrement length by one to delete the added space item and to enable to get the non spaced item as the last element.

Comment: Well spotted about the extra `1`,  came to me while sat on throne, there was a slight bug.. :)

Answer (score 4):

One possible idea:

Assuming you want three `2`s, start with `2 1 2 1 2`. Until the desired length is reached, insert an `1` into 4 possible positions `_ 2 1 _ 2 1 _ 2 _`, selected at random.